# OpenCVS como sacar una lista de objetos leída con CSVreader en Java

Tags: java

Estoy leyendo un archivo de Alumnos con CSVreader, solo puedo leerlos pasarlos a una lista y mostrarlos por pantalla.

Como podría hacer para obtener esa lista desde otra clase???

CLASE  LectorDeArchivosCSV

```
package Lector;

import DigitalHouseManager.Alumno;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LectorDeArchivosCSV{


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        CSVReader csvReader = null;

        try
        {
            /*
            * Reading the CSV File
            * Delimiter is comma
            * Start reading from line 1
            */
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("././data/listadoDeAlumnos.csv"),',','"',1);

            //List for holding all the rows
            List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            //Lista de tipo Alumno.
            List<Alumno> listadoAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();

            rows = csvReader.readAll();
            //Read individual row from List of rows
            if(rows != null){ for(String[] row : rows)
            {
                Alumno unAlumno = new Alumno(row[1],row[2], Integer.valueOf(row[0]));
                listadoAlumnos.add(unAlumno);
            }

            System.out.println(listadoAlumnos);

            } }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                //closing the reader
                csvReader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Desde ya, Muchas Gracias!!!!!

Comment: Añade el codigo de la otra clase desde donde quieres obtener la lista.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que preguntas podría solucionarse con esto:

```
package Lector;

import DigitalHouseManager.Alumno;
import java.util.List;

public class LectorDeArchivosCSV{

    List<Alumno> listadoAlumnos = LectorDeArchivosCSV.read("././data/listadoDeAlumnos.csv");

    //Lo que quieras hacer ahora 

}
```

Y la clase lector:

```
package Lector;

import DigitalHouseManager.Alumno;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LectorDeArchivosCSV{


    public static void read(String filePath)
    {
        CSVReader csvReader = null;

        try
        {
            /*
            * Reading the CSV File
            * Delimiter is comma
            * Start reading from line 1
            */
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath),',','"',1);

            //List for holding all the rows
            List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            //Lista de tipo Alumno.
            List<Alumno> listadoAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();

            rows = csvReader.readAll();
            //Read individual row from List of rows
            if(rows != null){ for(String[] row : rows)
            {
                Alumno unAlumno = new Alumno(row[1],row[2], Integer.valueOf(row[0]));
                listadoAlumnos.add(unAlumno);
            }

            return listadoAlumnos;

            } }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            ee.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                //closing the reader
                csvReader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                ee.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```